# Motion tracking 3D Markers to Mesh creates vertices but how can I use in Geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, motion-capture

I was only able to make e correct motion tracking by placing (real phisical) small objects on the ground and table when shooting the footage.
I want to remove these in the final render and used the "3D Marker to Mesh" option. According to documentation, this created a Mesh with only vertices. All correct and I manually use these on several ways. But I don't want to do this for each vertice and created a Geometry Node to assign a sphere each vertice. But some how the vertices are not recognized by GN.
I used Instance on Points and when it did not worked added Mesh to Points. But nothing happens.
Any idea what I am doing wrong? Or are these "Motion tracking vertices" of a different kind.

Comment: any screenshots?

Comment: Tried to add screenshots. Should be simple, click edit - click image symbol, select (small) file, and klik add.
But images do not appear. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get a mesh from those points, you can "fill" them by selecting groups of 4 vertices and pressing F.
After that in GN the mesh should be recognizable

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).